# Django can't read docker environment variable

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a docker compose environment and Django can't read the environment variables i try to give it.

Inside my `settings.py` i have this bit of code

```
...

import os

SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"]

DEBUG = os.environ["DEBUG"] == "True"

...
```

and this should be able to read the variables i give to the container, which i tried to give in many different ways.
This is the content of my envfile:

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="k64dpx9s1h!ijwafy-lif!(*)sabwk*w+rg#6=nu@ty2jkw%gc"
DEBUG="False"
```

All of the following result in django not being able to read the variables during docker build. These errors are generated during build, when i do some operations with `manage.py`.

---

### First attempt: env_file inside compose.yaml

This is my compose.yaml

```
services:
  django:
    env_file:
      - ./django/.env
```

##### Error given: Keyerror (the key DJANGO_SECRET_KEY does not exist)

---

### Second attempt: changing env_file path

This is my compose.yaml

```
services:
  django:
    env_file:
      - /some/other/random/path
```

##### Error given: no such file or directory (don't mess around with files that don't exist, the file location is correct)

---

### Third attempt: hardconding variables

This is my compose.yaml

```
services:
  django:
    environment:
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "k64dpx9s1h!ijwafy-lif!(*)sabwk*w+rg#6=nu@ty2jkw%gc"
      DEBUG: "False"
    env_file:
      - ./django/.env
```

##### Error given: Keyerror (the key DJANGO_SECRET_KEY does not exist)

---

### Fourth attempt: running standalone container

I tried running a docker standalone container and giving the variables by cmd. This is not a desired use case, i just wanted to see if running as standalone changed something.

```
docker run -dp 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 \
   -e DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='k64dpx9s1h!ijwafy-lif!(*)sabwk*w+rg#6=nu@ty2jkw%gc' \
   -e DEBUG="False" django:v0
```

##### Error given: Keyerror (the key DJANGO_SECRET_KEY does not exist)

---

Thanks for reading this far. I hope no one will tell me to use `dict.get(key)` instead of `dict[key]` so it won't give me errors, when is better to get a error then a blank or default value.

---

## EDIT

Maybe this not working is for the better. i thought of many ways this can go wrong and i think i should just generate my key to a file while building the image. i did read of secrets in docker compose, but i don't think that enough security is provided.
While the problem still persists i edited my Dockerfile adding this line before the operations i do with django and `manage.py`:

```
RUN python -c 'from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key; print(get_random_secret_key())' >> /app/key
```

and now i read the secret key from there.

Comment: You shouldn't need this value during the image build (and publishing the key in plain text in your image will compromise it).  What part of the build needs it, and why?

Comment: @DavidMaze probably smth like `./manage.py collectstatic`. To make it work, SECRET_KEY is **not** necessary, but settings should be configurable, so `os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']` should not fail. I'd say that "use `.getenv` instead of hard dict lookup, but OP rejected this for some reason. If you **really** need to pass that as build args, find the dupe question below.

Comment: @STerliakov i don't understand how this should resolve my issue . Maybe this is on me because i listed the fourth attempt, but my goal is to run the whole thing with docker compose, not with CMD

Comment: Does the KeyError happen when the django app tries to run inside the docker container, or when you're running a django management command in your local environment?

Comment: @JohnGordon as written above i get all these errors during the build of the docker container. specifically while i do some operations with my ```manage.py```

Comment: If it's during the build, then that means the django command is running in your actual real environment.  The .env file is only used inside the container.

Comment: What **actual command** does the error come from?  Are you typing something like `python manage.py collectstatic` at a command prompt?

Comment: @JohnGordon correct. I also just tried to set a variable in my shell named `DEBUG` and composing the enviroment. i get the same issue stated in the post

Comment: The `.env` file is only used for the django app running inside the container.  If you're running a command in your local environment, then those variables need to be in your actual local environment.  When you get the KeyError, does it say what the specific key is?  I imagine you'll need to set more than just DEBUG.

Comment: Also as a side comment, django expects DEBUG to be a boolean true/false value in settings.py.  But because you're using a string value from the environment, it's going to interpret the string "False" as a true value, because in python, non-empty strings are considered "truthy" values, and the string "False" is a non-empty string.

Comment: @JohnGordon the error that i get is specifically on the line where i try to read `DEBUG`, 
here's a portion of the stacktrace
`0.308   File "/myapp/myapp/settings.py", line 29, in <module>`  
`0.308     DEBUG = os.environ["DEBUG"]`  
`0.308   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__`  
`0.308     raise KeyError(key) from None`  
`0.308 KeyError: 'DEBUG'`
 
I also tried running a python shell in my local environment and i can read the enviroment variable i set before.

Comment: If you're able to do `os.environ["DEBUG"]` in a python shell, then I don't understand why you would get the error from manage.py.

Comment: @Tox46 docker build does not inherit environment variables from your local environment. That's where the duplicate STerliakov had suggested would be useful to you. To put it simply there are 3 environments. 1) Your local environment, 2) Environment for docker build 3) The container run by docker compose. Point 3 is entirely a distraction since that container isn't even run yet, you're still at image building step.